# PyroStreams is adding an extra slash after 'files', before the image name in image urls?

Tags: pyrocms

PyroStreams is adding an extra slash into url's for some reason. The images display fine in all tested browsers, however my client is concerned. I've checked my .htaccess but I can't see where I would be causing this. This also happens within the streams interface, meaning I'm getting the extra slash in code I haven't touched.

This:

```
<img src="{{ hero:image }}" width="305" alt="">
```

Produces this:

```
<img src="http://rococ.co/grandhelo/pyroapp/site/uploads/default/files//ssvs-hero.jpg" width="305" alt="">
```

Here's the .htaccess for good measure:

```
# Multiple Environment config
# Set this to development, staging or production
# SetEnv PYRO_ENV production

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Make sure directory listing is disabled
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

# NOTICE: If you get a 404 play with combinations of the following commented out lines
#AllowOverride All
#RewriteBase /wherever/pyro/is

# Restrict your site to only one domain
# !important USE ONLY ONE OPTION

# Option 1: To rewrite "www.domain.com -> domain.com" uncomment the following lines.
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Option 2: To rewrite "domain.com -> www.domain.com" uncomment the following lines.
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove index.php from URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With}    !^XMLHttpRequest$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}              ^[^/]*/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$            $1 [R=301,NS,L]

# Keep people out of codeigniter directory and Git/Mercurial data
RedirectMatch 403 ^/(system\/cms\/cache|system\/codeigniter|\.git|\.hg).*$

# Send request via index.php (again, not if its a real file or folder)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Does anyone know how to stop this behavior, or have any insight that I could pass on to my client explaining how this is not a problem?

Comment: It's got nothing to do with htaccess, it's got to do with whatever code generates the image src. Is there a configuration path somewhere that has a trailing slash when it shouldn't?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.I haven't set any configuration paths, where can I find this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in the pyro_streams image filetype.

adamfairholm posted a fix:
https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/commit/f96cf0ac356935faea466c626a6f6ba829dc6684

```
304  304    
     {
305  305    
       $image = $db_obj->row();
306  306    

307     
-      $full = $this->CI->config->item('files:path') . '/' . $image->name;
     307    
+      $full = $this->CI->config->item('files:path').$image->name;
308  308    

309  309    
       $image_data['filename']    = $image->name;
310  310    
       $image_data['image']    = base_url().$full;
...  ...    
@@ -322,8 +322,8 @@ public function pre_output_plugin($input, $params)
322  322    
       if( file_exists( $path . '/'.$plain_name.'_thumb'.$image->extension ) )
323  323    
       {
324  324    

325     
-        $image_data['thumb']    = base_url().$this->CI->config->item('files:path') . '/' . $plain_name.'_thumb' . $image->extension;
326     
-        $image_data['thumb_img']  = img( array('alt'=>$image->name, 'src'=> $this->CI->config->item('files:path') . '/' . $plain_name.'_thumb' . $image->extension) );
     325    
+        $image_data['thumb']    = base_url().$this->CI->config->item('files:path').$plain_name.'_thumb' . $image->extension;
     326    
+        $image_data['thumb_img']  = img( array('alt'=>$image->name, 'src'=> $this->CI->config->item('files:path').$plain_name.'_thumb' . $image->extension) );
327  327    
       }
328  328    
       else
329  329    
       {
```